# Pixelated fonts in Safari when using tap to zoom

Tags: macos, safari, osx-lion, zoom, anti-aliasing

In OS X Lion 10.7, when using Safari, I double tap content and it is zoomed. Everything works well, but some of the fonts seem jaggy. There is no anti-aliasing when zoomed. Pulling back to actual size, everything looks nice and smooth again.

Even on this page, the text I write in the comment box is anti-aliased, but the preview text looks jaggy.

How do I force it to anti-alias text when zooming in?

Comment: Are the fonts rendered normally when using *View - Zoom In / Out*?

Comment: I can't seem to duplicate the problem.

Comment: Lri - Yes, everything is nicely aliased, but when I double tap the page and smartZoom takes place the fonts are not aliased, at least not all.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the system-wide Zoom feature (which is controlled in System Preference: Universal Access), when you are in an application like Safari you should use Safari's "Zoom In" command, which can be found under the View menu or accessed by using the Command + key combination. That will properly display the text with no jaggies.

Similarly, most all word processor or spreadsheet programs have an internal zoom command that uses proper font rendering.

Comment: right, but that is how it used to be. now the more convenient  gesture smart zoom is here, and why should it be any different ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of 'zoom' in a web browser. There's a raster zoom where the browser takes the existing image and makes it bigger, but will result in fuzzy images and jagged edges.

The other 'zoom' is done by adjusting the text size, which, depending on how the website is coded, might just cause the font size of text to increase, or might also cause the layout to adjust up in size as well.

As someone else mentioned earlier, you are doing the first type of zoom, and you want to be doing the second type.